# How does `solnp()` in the Rsolnp package handle the default LB and UB arguments?

Tags: r

I ultimately want to constrain one of the variables between two numbers. Naturally, I would like to use the `LB` or `UB` arguments in `solnp()`. Before adjust the constraints to fit my needs, I would be more confident if I can replicate the default behavior by using the `LB` and `UB` constraints in `solnp()`. The optimal answer should be the same regardless if I use the default of these arguments (`NULL`) or `LB = -Inf` and `UB = Inf` for all variables, as the parameter space would be the same. Specifying  `+-Inf`, I get an error that does not make any sense to me.

For instance, using the `solnp()` example in Rsolnp package, the original problem is:

```
   min   exp(x[1]*x[2]*x[3]*x[4]*x[5]) 
   subject to: sum(x[i]^2) = 10  
               x[2]*x[3]-5*x[4]*x[5] = 0
               x[1]^3  + x[2] ^ 3 = -1
```

The solution is as follows.

```
library(Rsolnp)
# POWELL Problem
fn1=function(x){
  exp(x[1]*x[2]*x[3]*x[4]*x[5])
}

eqn1=function(x){
  z1=x[1]*x[1]+x[2]*x[2]+x[3]*x[3]+x[4]*x[4]+x[5]*x[5]
  z2=x[2]*x[3]-5*x[4]*x[5]
  z3=x[1]*x[1]*x[1]+x[2]*x[2]*x[2]
  return(c(z1,z2,z3))
}
x0 = c(-2, 2, 2, -1, -1)

#Orginal Example
powell=solnp(x0, fun = fn1, eqfun = eqn1, eqB = c(10, 0, -1))
```

yields

```
> powell$pars
[1] -1.7171436  1.5957097  1.8272457 -0.7636431 -0.7636430
> powell$convergence
[1] 0
```

I want to replicate the result by adding lower and upper bound constraints to be broad, say +- infinity. Instead of the original optimization problem, I want to optimize

```
   min   exp(x[1]*x[2]*x[3]*x[4]*x[5]) 
   subject to: sum(x[i]^2) = 10  
               x[2]*x[3]-5*x[4]*x[5] = 0
               x[1]^3  + x[2] ^ 3 = -1 
               -Inf < x[i] < Inf for i = 1, ..., 5
```

where in this problem, I added the last constraint. Since I am letting the optimizer minimize the function in the whole parameter space, I expect to get the same answer. But ...

```
#Add lower bounds
A2=solnp(x0, fun = fn1,
         eqfun = eqn1, eqB = c(10, 0, -1),
         LB = rep(-Inf, 5), UB = rep(Inf, 5)
)
Iter: 1 fn: 0.0003355    Pars:  -2.00000  2.00000  2.00000 -1.00000 -1.00000
solnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.
Warning message:
In p0 * vscale[(neq + 2):(nc + np + 1)] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

After looking at the source code of `solnp()`,  I have a few questions:

1. Using the LB and UB arguments to cover the whole parameter space results in a different answer than using the default values. Does anyone know how the default values of `LB = NULL` and `UB = NULL` are handled?
2. I don't know what the warning means.
3. Is there another way to replicate the default answer by using the additional constraint options in `solnp()`: `ineqLB`, `ineqUB`, or `LB` or `UB`?

Thanks!

PS: I know that infinite LB and UB arguments are changed to +/- .Machine$double.xmax/2 (eg. ~ 9e+307) values in the `solnp()` function.